# Airbag light is on in my dash

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, supplemental-restraint-system

Hi guys I have a big problem and it’s my own fault I have a Silverado single cab it’s a 2001 and me being careless I cut the wires going under my seat and to the belt buckle sensor I didn’t notice till a week later I know I’m a dumbass but I need help what should I do I threw away the original wires and module box that was under there

Comment: Local salvage yard “Pick-A-Part” ??

Comment: Salvage yard is about your only hope

Comment: For future reference ... don't mess with the yellow wires. Or yellow anything. It pretty much ALL belongs to the airbag system.

Comment: If you try to replace anything to do with the airbags, please unhook the battery and wait 5 minutes before repairs. After repairs then hook battery back up.

Comment: Did you throw away the small silver box with yellow label under the mat? That would be your SRS module and will require a bit of programming to replace If so I will post an answer with steps needed to replace it. If you just tossed a smaller sensor under the seat then that may not be as bad and local junk yard is a good option as suggested by Paulster and Zipzit, Also Jupiter offers sounds advice however it is most important to have the ignition  switch turned to the off position even if the battery is unhooked.